# Turning a highly upvoted answer over to Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, support

Okay this is my scenario,
With respect to the question: [A good puzzle is a double-edged sword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18782/a-good-puzzle-is-a-double-edged-sword/20311#20311)

I am still not satisfied with my answer and have clearly hit the top-end as far as my skill level goes. I am not concerned at all with reputation, I want to know what the darned inscription says. I would like to make my answer into a community wiki in hopes of encouraging others to jump in and maybe get a definitive answer on the inscription, AND keep it penalty free.

Am I understanding the function of a Community wiki correctly? Also if this is an agreaable way to go, will the answer still remain on the same page as the Question? Alternately can I shift what "research" is contained in my answer to a seperate entry in the same page and make that a community wiki instead. I've been writing Catholic clergy and some religious orders to ask questions when and where i can in an effort to find out if the inscription can be used to narrow down the owner of the sword to a particular group but, have not recieved many responses so that is still ongoing.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I can turn the answer into CW if you'd like. The answer will remain on the page, but you'll stop earning reputation from it, and the amount of reputation needed to freely edit it is reduced to 15 (if I recall correctly). However, since it's entirely work that you've done, I'd be hesitant to do it. Are you sure you'd like me to do that?

Comment: @Emrakul thank you for your reply, i would like to stay "in the game", as per my FINAL GUESS section which is my answer but have that answer at an honest zero and let the users weigh in. I would like to seperate the research portion to community wiki. This is a really neat mystery and i'm enjoying it immensley. Is there a middle ground to achieve both?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but a community wiki answer for collecting research seems like it could work. Maybe someone else from the community has a better idea, too.

Comment: @Emrakul okay, final question , can i repurpose a previously deleted answer with 2 upvotes to contain my final guess and then turn over the main body to community wiki as proposed? Or post a new answer with my final and then do the handover?

Comment: "in hopes of encouraging others to jump in" - well, they can always post their own answers, referring to yours if necessary.

Comment: @rand al'thor , hi thanks for your reply, i should have mentioned that i have this neurotic tick thing which has kicked in over this subject and subjects similar which has literally been interfering with my sleep for days.

Comment: Turned over to Community Wiki, blessed sleep.